Who do I contact about a typo on documentation available through ubuntu.com
I recently downloaded the Ubuntu 24.04 Live Server iso. While the download started, I saw the 2024 Ubuntu CLI cheatsheet download was available. I noted that inside this document, the section for Firewall as well as SSH were duplicated on the second page.
Who do I contact to raise issue about the documentation?

https://ubuntu.com/download/server/thank-you?version=24.04&architecture=amd64&lts=true

Bottom of the page you linked: "Report a bug on this site"
